# ProgressBar is not stopped after Completing Background Execution in Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I am working in Android Technology.In my application i am fetching the data from web service i used A sync Task for consuming web service.It show the data correctly on Toast i.e true or false but My Progress Bar is  continuously moving it does not stopped when Background task completed its execution i called dismiss method in onPostExecute().But it failed to dismiss the progress bar.Again it start calling  web service but progress bar is not dismmed.

Can you tell me what i did wrong in my code.Please solve my problem..

I am attaching source code here

Async task

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please Wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);
            pd.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            v=new Validate();
            String result;
            result=v.SendParam(url,user,pass);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Here id Validate.java code

```
class Validate 
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevaluepair;
    InputStream is;
    String res;
    public String SendParam(String url,String username,String password)
    {

        try
        {
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
        // add parameter here
        namevaluepair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",username));
        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepair));
        HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        is=entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Httpconnection","error",e);  
        } 
        // read response from
        try
        {

             BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
             StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
             String line;
              while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
              {
                  builder.append(line+"\n");

              }
              is.close();
              res=builder.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("reading Input Stream","",e);
        }
        return res;


    }

}
```

Comment: where do you declared pd?

Comment: in the mainActivity i believe @blackbelt

Comment: i declared pd in MainActivity.ProgressDialog pd;

Comment: is there any chance that you are showing it in another place, overriding the object's reference?

Comment: is there any error in your `LogCat`?

Comment: can you please check the Logcat and post it

Comment: HERE IS SHOWN IS LOG CAT Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: PLEASE GIVE ME SOLUTION

Comment: I tested your code just now and it seems to dismiss the pd very well. Be careful because u sure have an error logged in your `LogCat` thrown by sendParam and that's why you can't reach the `onPostExecute` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work fine (the dialog should be dismissed without problems).
However I'm guessing your sendParam method is throwing an error, and so the `onPostExecute` method is not reached. Replace `doInBackground` with this in your code :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try {
        v=new Validate();
        String result;
        result=v.SendParam(url,user,pass);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
super.onPostExecute(result);
```

Try to remove this and execute. hope it works.

Comment: remove both super  line in the code and inform me  if it works or not